# parallel execution within a Flask response context?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, concurrency, concurrent.futures, dokku

I'm trying to stream some data back to the user as a CSV in Flask, but need to get some extra info for each row.  This means I'm in the `Response` and want to call a method for each row in parallel.

Here's some pseudo-code to describe the situation:

```py
def endpoint:
    return Response(stream_data_by_page(arguments), mimetype='text/csv; charset=utf-8', headers=headers)

def row_worker(id):
    extra_info = get_more_info(id)
    return {'id': id, 'info': extra_info}

def stream_data_by_page(arguments):
    rows = get_data_page(arguments)
    # now add data to each row from another call
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        jobs = [row['id'] for row in rows]
        job_results = executor.map(row_worker, jobs)
        results_lookup = {j['id']:j['info'] for j in job_results}
    for row in rows:
        yield ','.join(row + results_lookup[row['id']]) + '\n'
```

This works locally, but dies within my Dokku container on the server.  I tried this with `Process.pool`, `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, and `Flask-Executor`. All produced the same failure (the process in my container just dies).

It works fine if I don't try to stream it (ie. if I make the parallel call inside the endpoint rather than in the Response), but streaming it really helps the user experience.

Any tips on how to approach this?